# WearOS HCE support

Tags: android, nfc, wear-os, hce

Does anyone know when Google will enable third party app developers to allow using `HostCardEmulationService` in WearOS ? As of now when I write a WearOS app to use the `HostApduService`, I never get a call to the `processCommandApdu()` method in `HostApduService` while trying to tap at the NFC readers in WearOS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, The HostCardEmulationService works well for third party apps as well. If we have the proper settings in AndroidManifest, they work right!.

Comment: Would you please share the proper settings? I also never get a call to the processComandApdu()?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if there are any existing Android smartwatches that support reading NDEF data from NFC tags (most recent Android phones do support)? I can't find any in US. The latest Fossil Sports Smartwatch with WearOS and most Android smartwatches including Samsung Gear ones only support NFC Payment, not NFC tag data reading.

Also, since I'm a NFC newbie, any WearOS-based code samples that show reading data from NFC tags?

The bottom line is that I'd like to confirm whether NFC tag reading is currently available in both API level and smartwatch hardware level.  Thanks in advance.